# Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError

Tags: node.js, connection-refused

I run my `server.js` file and I have this error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4305
at Handshake._callback >   (c:\Users\alexa\WebstormProjects\ToDoSPA\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:76:20)
at Handshake.Sequence.end (c:\Users\alexa\WebstormProjects\ToDoSPA\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:96:24)
at Protocol.handleNetworkError (c:\Users\alexa\WebstormProjects\ToDoSPA\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:364:14)
at Connection._handleNetworkError (c:\Users\alexa\WebstormProjects\ToDoSPA\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:384:18)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1253:8)
at doNTCallback2 (node.js:452:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:366:17)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory: your Node code cannot connect to port 4305 of localhost.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but I don't understand why, and what do I have to do in order to make things work..I am not running anything else on port 4305

Answer (score 7):

You didn't start your database or wrong database config 
check db config:

 `var sequelize = new Sequelize(<your config>)`

or start Database

Answer (score 5):

Start your database server. It's coming because your database server is not running yet, that's why it refused the connection from app to database.

Answer (score 4):

On **macOS**, I had the same problem.
The reason is Postgres service is not properly started. Make sure via running the command-
`brew services list`
Status of Postgres one will be yellow(not properly started) and others are green(means properly started)

**The solution is for macOS**(Run below 3 command one by one in your terminal),

```
rm -f /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
brew services restart postgresql
brew services list
```

Now you can see hopefully the status of postgresql is green too. Now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DataBase connection, if you are using localhost, Don't forget to turn on the localhost connection.
In my case, after open connection in Postgresql by typing

`sudo service postgresql start`

it works fine.